# Sending chunks of data sequentially on request from a Laravel api to Angular

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am trying to show comments on my frontend so that they are displayed like facebook comments. Initially you see only few comments and then on scroll you get more comments displayed. I am using Laravel as a backend and Angular for frontend.
What I am wondering is how to send from the frontend request for next chunk of data until all of the comments are displayed and make it in Laravel to perform queries for the next chunk at the request?

Answer (score 0):

Paginate the data on the server and when the user gets on the page, he/she will see only 10 comments for example, but when he/she clicks on the view 10 more comments, show the next page of comments, which are stored as chunks of 10 inside the Paginator object.

The same idea would apply if you wanna display the comments on scroll down.

Build a custom JSON response so you can easily work with it on the front end.

Check out the Laravel Paginator API:

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html